# Questions about Sylvester's Criterion and an algorithm to find the signature of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have learned that Sylvester's Criterion (which I initially learned as "Sylvester's Theorem" and later found that term was quite ambiguous after some research) is equivalent to the statement:

Any symmetric matrix $M$ can be be put in the form $XMX^T$, where $XMX^T$ is a diagonalized matrix with a sequence of 1's, then -1's, and then 0's in the diagonal. The amount of 1's, -1's, and 0's is the signature of the matrix. If there are no -1's, then $M$ is positive. If there are only 1's in the diagonal, then $M$ is positive definite.

The algorithm I have been taught is to simultaneously row and column reduce the matrix by choosing a matrix $X$ to perform an operation, then immediately after using the matrix $X^T$ to "do what I do to the rows to the columns". I am not very good at this, but I see why it works. After a few steps, you would get to the form 
$$X_n..X_2XMX^TX_2^T...X_n^T$$ 
I also understand, if I wanted to, I could start with the transpose instead to get
$$X_n^T..X^TMX..X_n$$
and I would still have the same form. I have learned that the reason we can do these operations with the transpose of a matrix is because the transpose follwos the axioms of the generalized inner product. I do not understand this quite as well, namely, why are we allowed to say that 
$$\left \langle x| y \right \rangle = x^TMy$$
for a matrix that has a signature of only 1's? What does this have to do with orthogonality? I get that an inner product space defines geometry for a vector space, but what exactly does it have to do with the transpose?

Comment: It's been a couple of decades since I took linear algebra, but... your $x^T M y$ defines AN inner product, and there are theorems that tell you how to express it in terms of the usual inner product (under some conditions)

Comment: @nomen yes, totally get that, that's why I said "generalized" inner product. So it is valid to call that *an* inner product because the transpose *acts* like an inner product given $M$ is the right kind of matrix?

Comment: Yes.  It just is "an" inner product.